# MacBook Air: Playing 1080p vs 720p videos

Tags: macbook-pro, display, video, resolution

I  have a MacBook Air 13-inch 2013 model and I was wondering if it is worth downloading **1080p movies** if I have the option for **720p**?

I know 1080p is much more crisp on my TV, but does the MacBook Air have enough resolution to even see the difference?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49144/discussion-on-question-by-kshikhar-macbook-air-13-inch-2013-1080p-vs-720p-vid).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MacBook Air supports the following resolutions at 16:10 aspect ratio:

- 1440 x 900 (native)
- 1280 x 800
- 1152 x 720
- 1024 x 640

It also supports the following at 4:3 aspect ratio:

- 1024 x 768
- 800 x 600

Since 1080p is technically a resolution of 1920 x 1080 your MacBook Air isn't going to display a 1080p movie at its best on its built in display. However, your MacBook Air does support an external resolution of up to 2560 x 1600 pixels, so you'd be able to take advantage of 1080p in that scenario.

Finally, whether you download 1080p or 720p movies also gets down to personal preference. Most people I know with true HD TVs still only download 720p versions because the difference to them (especially while watching most movies) is negligible. Basically, do you notice the extra pixels during a high speed chase in an action movie or not? Many people don't, some people do.

In summary, if you're downloading movies **only** to watch on your MacBook Air via it's built in display, there's no real advantage to downloading the 1080p version.

Comment: If you do care about quality, though, even when viewing them on your MacBook Air it will look better to have the 1080p video. A 1080p video scaled down will look better than a 720p video scaled up, and believe it or not, even a 1080 video scaled down to 720 will look better than a 720p video at native resolution! It all comes down to how much you care about quality. If you can't tell the difference, then there's no need to use the extra disk space.

Comment: @timothymh That's true about the scaling and I actually agree with your comment. It's just that I can't tell you how many people have said to me something like "What's the big deal about 1080p, I can't tell the difference" or "I can barely tell the difference". Some of them have even felt _ripped off_ by the whole thing. I even had a guy once in front of a 5K iMac who said he couldn't tell the difference between that and his 21" mid-2010 iMac. As for myself, having previously worked in the video editing/DVD authoring industry, I can tell the difference, but over 90% of my clients couldn't.