# Getting original resolution from iMovie

Tags: video, resolution, imovie

I imported a screencapture recording into iMovie and added some headings. I'm trying to export it as a file with the same resolution as the original recording. Unfortunately, it looks like I only get the choice of 720p or 540p. Either of those makes the text very blurry.

How can I make sure the exported movie preserves the original resolution of the imported clip?

Comment: What was the mac's resolution it was recorded on ?

Comment: @ankii 1440x900

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262511/macbook-air-playing-1080p-vs-720p-videos I don't think MacBook Air will do any better. But still, I am an iMovie noob, so good luck for a better answer.